# How to access these objects?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I want to access some data from an object but got no idea how :/

```
exif:
   name: ''
   {GPS}:
```

When I inspect the exif object it's got an {GPS} parameter but got no idea how can I access {} elements inside an object.

[image]

Comment: That isn't JavaScript or JSON.

Comment: It's JS, wait I update it so it's will be more obvious (with a picture)

Comment: You cannot wrap keys inside brackets in JSON, it's not according to the [`specification`](https://www.json.org/).

Comment: It's not me who wrap it, this is how I receive it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
var obj = {"{GPS}" : "value"};
console.log(obj["{GPS}"]);
```

Comment: Cheers mate! :)

Comment: @IstvanOrban - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Here, you can work like this.

```js
var obj = { "exif" : {"{Exif}" : {"v" : "1"}}};

console.log(obj.exif["{Exif}"]);
```